# Adding dynamic bootstrap carousel Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carousel, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Hello I have seen similar questions been asked but could not find a tutorial on how to create a dynamic bootstrap carousel in ruby on rails. The admin of my site needs to be able to browse and upload images rather than having to change any code. I have tried a carrier wave approach but was unable to get it working.

Here is my current carousel which is hard coded.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('assets/banner2.jpg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('assets/Banner3.png')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('assets/SaleHero1.jpg')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Obviously at the moment if you want to change the images to something else it has to be done through the code. Could some point me in the right direction to get this task completed. Thank you :)

Comment: why didn't carrier wave work? What is the error message you're getting?    Also can you be more specific about what you mean by "dynamic"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can figure out how to upload images using carrier wave, you'll need to use ERB in your views.

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
  <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: <%= images.url %>)">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You'll need to create a mode like `image.rb` which would need to store the images uploaded URL assuming you'll use an AWS S3 bucket.  Then you'll need your code to store the url of the images in an attribute like `url`

Then in your controller you'll need something like:

```
def index
  @images = Image.all.limit(10) # or however many images you wanna use
end
```